# Azure Search : Blob only Index Creation

Tags: azure-cognitive-search, azure-search-.net-sdk

We would like to enable Azure Search only for Blob data, including its Contents and Meta Attributes stamped on the blob.

Is it possible to have such Indexer & Index without any reference to the database? How are the Fields of the Index specified in this case? Will the fields be same as meta attributes stamped on the blob?

Also, we have certain fields which may contain data from two different languages. Is it possible to add same field twice in the Index, with different language analyzer specified on each?

Is it possible to related same Indexer to two different Indexes?

Is it possible to specify more than one Storage Account Container as data source for the same Index?

Ideally, we would like to be able to do the following;

1. Utilize same Indexer in multiple Indexes
2. Enable same Indexer/Index to be able to search for Multiple Languages (with language analyzers)
3. Enable Index based only on Blob & its Meta attributes data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doc topic explains how to setup search for blob data: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-howto-indexing-azure-blob-storage

The default `dataToExtract` parameter value is `contentAndMetadata`, meaning all text content and metadata will be indexed. You should be able to set-up field mappings from metadata and contents to your index (the details are outlined in this same doc topic).

The indexer points to the index it should output to, so I don't think it would be possible to re-use the same indexer for multiple indexes, and you'll have to copy them instead.

Similarly, the indexer specifies what datasource it takes its data from, so only one data source per indexer. You'd need to aggregate your data into a single source first if you want to build an index from the data of multiple sources.

It is possible to index multiple languages in a single index, by specifying the relevant analyzer for each index field. More details can be found in this topic: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-language-support